# May someone explain this decorator code to me?

Tags: python

*The code has been taken from Learning Python 4th Edition by Mark Lutz*

```
class tracer:
            def __init__(self, func):
               self.calls = 0
               self.func = func
            def __call__(self, *args):
               self.calls += 1
               print('call %s to %s' % (self.calls, self.func.__name__))
               self.func(*args)


@tracer

def spam(a, b, c):
    print(a + b + c)

spam(1, 2, 3)
```

Also, when I run this code, it doesn't print the sum of 1,2,3 either, but in the book, it's shown that it does! 
I am left scratching my head at this entire code. I have no idea what is going on in here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's happening here is the body of the function is being replaced. A decorator like so

```
@tracer
def spam(...)
   ...
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
def spam(...)
   ...
spam = tracer(spam)
```

Now, `tracer(spam)` returns an instance of the `tracer` class where the original definition of `spam` is stored in `self.func`

```
class tracer:
            def __init__(self, func):  #tracer(spam), func is assigned spam
               self.calls = 0
               self.func = func
```

Now when you call `spam`, (which is actually an instance of `tracer`) you invoke the `__call__` method defined in the `tracer` class:

```
def __call__(self, *args):
   self.calls += 1
   print('call %s to %s' % (self.calls, self.func.__name__))
```

So in essense this `__call__` method has *overriden* the body origianlly defined in `spam`. To have the body execute, you need to call the function stored in the instance of the `tracer` class like so:

```
def __call__(self, *args):
               self.calls += 1
               print('call %s to %s' % (self.calls, self.func.__name__))
               self.func(*args)
```

Resulting in

```
>>> 
call 1 to spam
6
```

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that you are not doing anything with `*args`. Is it possible there is a missing line of `__call__`?

```
class tracer:
    def __init__(self, func):
       self.calls = 0
       self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args):
       self.calls += 1
       print('call %s to %s' % (self.calls, self.func.__name__))
       return self.func(*args)
```

Recall that the decorator syntax is just another way of saying this

```
def spam(a, b, c):
    print(a + b + c)
spam = tracer(spam)
```

so spam becomes an *instance* of the tracer class and `spam` is passed into the `__init__` method and is saved to `self.func`

Now when spam is called, you are calling that instance of tracer, so the `__call__` method is used.

The usual do nothing `__call__` wrapper is

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
    return self.func(*args, **kw)
```

I don't know why he hasn't included the support for keyword arguments, but ignoring that, you see that there are just two extra lines in there that are run every time that tracer instance is called.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, my mistake, I forgot to add the last line. Still, I am unable to comprehend this code.